# Number of days for UK Visa

Tags: visas

I am an Indian student.

I will be attending a conference in UK(Edinburgh) for a week.

Do I have to specify in my visa application form that I want to stay (roam around) in UK for another week or they usually sanction Visa for 30 days or so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application should definitely tell the full truth about the trip you're planning.

If you deliberately hide part of your plans in the application, that can create real problems for you in subsequent applications, **even if** what you're doing is itself within the limits of the visa you're given, and **even if** what you're doing is itself innocuous. You'd get yourself labeled as "someone whose claims in the visa application we can't trust".

On the other hand, there's not much *reason* to hide the week of tourism. If you can afford to eat and sleep during that week, and you won't find yourself thrown out of your studies and job for being absent in that period (which I assume you can; otherwise you wouldn't ask), then you don't need to meet any higher burden for the visa. After all, the main risk they want to guard against is that you stay illegally once you've entered, and it's not going to make that risk any *less* likely to say that you can only come if you leave *immediately* after the conference.

Comment: I did not want to hide anything.. that was not the point.. some one said they usually sanction visa for 3/4 weeks minimum if I can show I can eat and sleep.. :D I was asking if they even care to ask about this,..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: The application asks you for when you intend to enter and leave the country. In order **not** to disclose your plans to stay for tourism, you would need to -- pretty deliberately! -- give false answers to one those questions.

Comment: Oh. Ok. Ok. I understand. Thank you for the information :)

Comment: I wanted to ask as separate question but not sure if that is ok.. I am getting accommodation from organisers for 7 days and I will be staying in uk for 12 days,, should I give them accommodation details of whole 12 days or it it sufficient to give just for 7 days.. I do not wish to stay in one place so did not book any accommodation yet..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: You should tell the full truth about your plans as they exist at the time you're applying. If you have a particular place to stay in mind, say that. If you don't have selected a particular place yet, say _that_.